# How to use relative paths to load .RData files from working directory?

Tags: r, relative-path

I am trying to use the `load()` function to load an .RData file into my current R session. I open my code base by double clicking on the R project file in my directory and then attempt to load the .RData file by running `load('./Data/mydata.rdata')`. However, this returns a 'No such file or directory' error. I verified that the working directory is correct by using `getwd()`.

I figure I must be using incorrect syntax because I have no issues loading the file when I  type in the full file path.

**Working directory for R Project file:** "/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff"

**Directory containing .RData file:** "/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff/Data"

**Code that works:** `load("/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff/Data/mydata.rdata")`

**Code that fails:** `load('./Data/mydata.rdata')`

Do relative paths not work with `load()` or is my syntax wrong?

Comment: R is case sensitive, shouldn't it be `mydata.RData`? Or maybe try `file.path(getwd(), "mydata.rdata")`.

Answer (score 0):

> Do relative paths not work with load() or is my syntax wrong?

It looks like there is an error with your paths. You said the working directory is `"/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff"`

But according to the code that works:

```
load("/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff/Data/mydata.rdata")
```

...the data file is in `"/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff/Data"`

Therefore to use relative paths, you would use:

```
load("./Data/mydata.rdata")
```

Comment: I made an error in my post, the path I was using was indeed "./Data/mydata.rdata". For unknown reasons my working directory is listed as "/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff" when I call getwd(), yet my true working directory appears to be two folders deeper: "/Users/Me/Library/OneDrive/RStuff/Other1/Other2".  I tried running load("../../Data/mydata.rdata") and the file loaded. Thank you for your input nevertheless.